# How to stop some css from getting applied to all <li> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my css file I have applied `before` to my `<li>` element as:

```
li:before {
 content: "";
 border-color: transparent #111;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
 display: block;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-left: 65px;
 width: 0;
 left: -1em;
 top: 0.8em;
 position: relative;
}
```

The problem is that once its included in my css file, my navigation-tab also includes this symbol which is something like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#t1" data-toggle="tab" >ABCD</a></li>
   <li><a href="#t2" data-toggle="tab">XYZ</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to tackle this ?

Comment: use a class name along with li to apply css to only to few elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override them like this:

```
.nav li:before {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li.YOURCLASS:before {
 content: "";
 border-color: transparent #111;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
 display: block;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-left: 65px;
 width: 0;
 left: -1em;
 top: 0.8em;
 position: relative;
}
```

or something like this:

```
li:first-child:before {
content: none;
}
```

This will disable all pseude elements for the fist list-item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this..If you want to apply style for only `Class_name`

**CSS**

```
Class_name:before {
 content: "";
 border-color: transparent #111;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
 display: block;
 font-size: 25px;
 position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the below css code, so that it will put the arrow image only in the first li (list Item)

```
li:first-child:before {
 content: "";
 border-color: transparent #111;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
 display: block;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-left: 65px;
 width: 0;
 left: -1em;
 top: 0.8em;
 position: relative;
}
```